# Object modelling of a simple application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, object, symfony1

I am having a confusion regarding object modeling, which I will illustrate using a simple lending library project.

The library has books (one copy for each book to keep things simple) and patrons. Patrons can loan a book, if that book is not loaned to another patron.

This will need 3 classes, Book, Patron and Loan.

Book will have an id and a name. Patron will have an id and name. Loan will have an id, book_id, patron_id and loan date.

Where will the loan and return method be defined? Is this a method of book, patron or loan object?

Book is the one getting lended, patron is the one who lends the book and loan is the one who keeps all details about the particular lending operation.

Why is Loan class really needed? Of course the DB table is needed with the fields mentioned above, but from an MVC framework perspective (eg: Symfony or Rails) should this be defined as a model?

I know this is a simple and solved problem, but after being out of touch with oop design for long, I am not quote able to "view" this problem correctly!

Comment: Thinking further into ShaunUK and sameera207's answer, I think I will need a library class, which holds the state of the library. It is the library which makes a loan, I can ask a library if a book is loaned or not. I can ask the library if a book is overdue and what is it's fine and so on. More thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class that is responsible for creating a Loan object. You could call this LoanCreator or if it is helpful for you to think of it in the following way you could call it Librarian. You would pass this new class a Book and a Patron object and it would create the Loan for you. Generally if you find yourself unsure if a method should belong to a particular class then perhaps it is time to consider creating a new class.

Comment: Basically this means I will need to rename the Loan object with LoanCreator object, with two methods, create_loan and return_book methods.

Comment: No because the loan is itself an object. It contains the data of the Loan. You need a separate class that handles the creation of the loans that has wider knowledge of the context, like if a book is already on loan.

Comment: Thanks for your input, again taking this further, In a physical library, there is lending registry, a physical book with an entry each for every book lent, mentioning the book, patron and date. After a book has been returned, the entry is "closed" and the return date is entered. This is the actual physical object used to keep track of the lending history. So while we are modeling this operation in real world, we will need a LendingRegistry (LR) object, which contains LendingRegistryEntries (LRE) object. LR will have search, add and save methods, while LRE will have create and close methods.

Comment: To lend a book, search the LR and see if  this book has been lent before, and if not create a new LRE object and add it to LR. To return a book, get the corresponding LRE entry from LR, close it and save it back.

Comment: Am I describing The Repository Pattern here?

Answer (score 1):

In my point of view you need 2 classes

1. Book
2. Patron

and

`loan` and `return` methods should go into `Book` class as those operations are happening to books. But as you said there should be a different loan table to keep these records.

When coming back to MVC, they should be implemented as models.

Comment: I am not really convinced that book class should have loan and return methods. Even though the book is getting loaned, in real world the state change happens to the library. Book's methods should be things like is_damaged etc which denote the attributes of the actual book.